# Pasar de .java a Binario

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class Employees implements Serializable{

    private final ArrayList<Employee> llistaEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Obte la llista d'llistaEmployees que conte la carpeta
     * @return ArrayList que conte les llistaEmployees de la carpeta
     */

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return llistaEmployees;
    }
}   


public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private String nom;
    private String empresa;
    private boolean jubilat;

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }    

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    } 

    public boolean isJubilat() {
        return jubilat;
    }

    public void setJubilat(boolean jubilat) {
        this.jubilat = jubilat;
    }

    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee (String nom,String empresa,boolean jubilat){
        this.nom=nom;
        this.empresa=empresa;
        this.jubilat=jubilat;
    }
}
```

Y tengo que hacer lo siguiente... Leer el archivo por ejemplo Datos.Txt que es donde tengo la información de los trabajadores y guardarlo en un archivo binario.

Es decir sé leer la información de un archivo externo pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer para que me lo guarde en otro formato usando estas clases..

Podéis ayudarme?

Por lo que creo entender sería.

1- Leer el archivo ( Lo tengo )

2- usarlo para crear una lista de empleados
3- guardar esa lista en un archivo binario.

Estoy bastante bloqueada.. acepto consejos.. ayuda.. ejemplos.. :(

Por ejemplo para leer el fichero externo uso esto:

```
public class LecturaFitxer {
    /**
    * Mètode per llegir les dades d'un fitxer.
    * @param filePath d'on llegirem la informació dels employees
    * @throws FileNotFoundException excepcio
    * @throws IOException excepcio
    */ 

    @SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
    public static void llegeixFitxer(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try {
            File origen = new File(filePath);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(origen);   
            String str; 

            while (reader.hasNextLine()){    
                str = reader.nextLine();    
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
                String[] strList = new String[st.countTokens()];

                for(int i=0; i<strList.length; i++){
                    strList[i] = st.nextToken();
                }

             System.out.println(strList[0]+"\t\t" +strList[1]+"\t" +strList[2]);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Error llegint el fitxer " + ex);
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        LecturaFitxer.llegeixFitxer(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que consigo es que arg[0] me lee el nombre, arg[1] la fecha de jubilación y el arg[2] la empresa.

Ahora lo que no sé es una vez leído el fichero con sus datos me utilice la clase employees y lo guarde todo en un archivo bin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes una clase employees lo que puedes hacer es ir creando un "employee" por cada vuelta del bucle WHILE y después del bucle FOR.

Después, en un "ArrayList" creado previamente por ejemplo, podrías ir metiendo los empleados nada más crearlos.

Por último puedes meter el ArrayList con los "employees" dentro en un archivo usando la clase ObjectOutputStream. Cuidado! Para poder guardar los objetos creados por tí necesitarán implementar la interfaz *Serializable*, aunque estén dentro de un "ArrayList".

**Clase Employee**
La clase employee será declaradá así:

```
Class Employee implements Serializable {
  //Contenido de la clase
}
```

**Metodo privado esJubilat() usando Java 7:**

En la misma clase donde haces las operaciones haces un metodo privado auxiliar que va a determinar si según la fecha de nacimiento del "employee" si jubilat es verdadero o falso. Este metodo se llama donde iria el parametro "jubilat" y tendrás que pasarle la fecha de nacimiento del "employee" que es según cuentas strList[1](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/archivos/objetos.htm).
El método es el siguiente:

```
public static boolean esJubilat(String fechaStr){

    String[] dma = fechaStr.split("/");
    int anio = Integer.parseInt(dma[2]);
    int mes = Integer.parseInt(dma[1]);
    int dia = Integer.parseInt(dma[0]);

    Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

    //Pasamos el año, el mes y el dia
    Calendar fechaNac = new GregorianCalendar(anio, mes, dia);

    if (fechaNac.after(hoy)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No se puede hacer en el futuro");
    }

    int edad = hoy.get(Calendar.YEAR) - fechaNac.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if(hoy.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < fechaNac.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
        edad-=1;
    }

    System.out.println("Años con Java7: "+edad);

    return edad >= 65;
}
```

---

**Método esJubilat usando Java8:**

Este es igual que el anterior pero más breve y fácil pero solo funciona si usas Java8

```
public static boolean esJubilat(String fechaStr) {
        //Version de Java8

        String[] dma = fechaStr.split("/");
        int anio = Integer.parseInt(dma[2]);
        int mes = Integer.parseInt(dma[1]);
        int dia = Integer.parseInt(dma[0]);

        LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.of(anio, mes, dia);
        LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
        Period p = Period.between(fechaNac, hoy);

        System.out.println("Años con Java 8: "+p.getYears());
        return (p.getYears() >= 65);
    }
```

Despues aparte t
ienes esto otro:

**Procedimiento:**

```
ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>(); //ArrayList para almacenar employees
try {
        File origen = new File(filePath);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(origen);   
        String str; 

        while (reader.hasNextLine()){    
            str = reader.nextLine();    
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
            String[] strList = new String[st.countTokens()];

            for(int i=0; i<strList.length; i++){
                strList[i] = st.nextToken();
            }

            //Crear employee e insertarlo en el ArrayList creado previamente
            //Cuidado al crear el empleado. Los parametros que le pasas al c onstructor deben estar en el mismo orden en el que están declarados en el constructor.
            //strList[0] es el nombre de tipo String.
            //strList[2] es la empresa de tipo String.
            //strList[1] es la fecha de tipo String en formato "dia/mes/año"
            //el constructor dice que es public Employee(nom, empresa, jubilat). Jubilat es booleano por lo tanto:

            Employee emp = new Employee(strList[0], strList[2], NombreDeClaseDondeEstaDeclaradoElMetodo.esJubilat(strList[1]));
            //Recuerda que si has delcarado el metodo en la misma clase puedes llamarlo directamente con el nombre del metodo o con this.nombreMetodo().
            //Si vas a usar el método solo en esta clase ponlo como private.

            emps.add(emp); //Añadir employee al ArrayList

            System.out.println(strList[0]+"\t\t" +strList[1]+"\t" +strList[2]);
        }
        reader.close();

        try{

          //Crear Stream de objetos
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("emps.bin");
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); //Recibe un FileOutputStream

          oos.writeObject(emps); //Escribir el ArrayList en el fichero

          oos.close();
          fos.close();
        } catch(IOException | ObjectStreamException exc) {
           System.out.println("Error en Stream de employees");
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error llegint el fitxer " + ex);
    }
```

[Aquí](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/archivos/objetos.htm) Un tutorial para ObjectOutputStream

[Otro](http://www.chuidiang.com/java/ficheros/ObjetosFichero.php) Tutorial de lectura y escritura de Objetos.

Con este método es realmente fácil guardar y sacar información en ficheros, guardando los Objetos tal cual serializados.

Cuando saques el ArrayList, luego solo tendras que recorrerlo para sacar la información que quieras del ArrayList.
Puedes usarlo con HashMaps también por ejemplo, si quieres guardar cada "employee" con una clave para poder obtener un employee en concreto más rapidamente.
Espero que haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Vale lo he conseguido pero tengo un error en esta linea:
 Employee emp = new Employee(strList[0], strList[1], strList[2]); me dice que STRList[2] es un boolean y no puede convertirse en String.. que hago?

Comment: @MontseMkd Seguramente tu clase Employee, en el parametro en el que iria strList[2] sea de tipo String por  lo que dic eel error y el valor de strList[2] es un booleano.
No pongas al pie de la letra como  lo he puesto yo. Asigna cada valor de strList al atributo de la clase que le corresponde.
Yo como no se como está construida la clase Employee no puedo saber donde va cada parametro. Lo mismo con strList. No sé los valores que tiene en cada posición ni a que atributo de la clase Employee corresponde así que lo puse así como ejemplo.

Comment: Bueno te lo he dicho al revés! xD El de la clase es boolean. El tema es que  estoy mirando pero no encuentro el error. Sé que tiene que estar en el bucle pero no sé como arreglarlo.

Comment: @MontseMkd Ah, la clase la has puesto. Podrías poner en un comentario lo que tiene cada posición de strList? Es decir, lo que recoges del fichero como texto? Porque  creo que sé lo que podría estar pasando

Comment: El problema creo que en jubilat es booleano por que tengo que añadir si es cierto o falso. Es decir cierto si tiene más de 65 años. Sino es falso.. Otra cosa añadir que no tengo ni idea de donde.

Comment: jubilat que valor tiene cuando lo coges?

Comment: Tienes el programa completo arriba. Es decir en employee sale toda la información. Supuestamente es nom ( nombre ) String, Empresa ( String ) y boolean Jubilado. ( Tengo que poner si es mayor de 65 es un true ) Otra cosa que no se donde poner.. no me mates! :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54646/discussion-between-montse-mkd-and-lorthas).

Comment: Ya he actualizado mi respuesta con  el método privado.

Comment: me da error esta parte:   Employee emp = new Employee(strList[0], strList[2], this.esJubilat(strList[1])); 

me dice non static variable... bla bla.. sabes el motivo? :(

Comment: Que dice el error del todo? Pusiste el método en la misma clase?
El procedimiento donde lo haces? En el main o en otro metodo de la clase?

Comment: non static variable this cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: Digamos que tengo 3 clases, Employee, Exployees y GravaFitxer. En grava Fitxer tengo el esJubilat() y todo el resto de programa de más arriba.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que estás llamando al método esJubilat que no es estatico dentro de un método estático, probablemente el Main?
Si es así para no complicarte, pon el método esJubilat como public en vez de private y añade la palabra static entre private y boolean.
Luego cuando lo llames en vez de usar this.esJubilat(etc) haz NombreDeClase.esJubilat. NombreDeClase será el nombre de la clase donde tienes declarado el método.

Comment: ya esta!! ^_^ mil graciaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas!!! :**********

Comment: Me alegro de veras de que te funcione! :)

Comment: vaya dos dias eh!! :P Ahora a por el siguiente! Nos seguimos leyendo! Seguro que me ves con más dudas! xD

Comment: Pues cualquier cosa pregunta sin problemas :). Encantado de ayudar, además es otra forma de practicar y aprender, jeje.

Answer (score 2):

A ver, lo más fácil, es lo que dice nuestro amigo "@Stefan Nolde", para que te quede mucho más claro, te daré un ejemplo completo, por tanto, lo primero;
El JavaBean de **Employe.java**, debe implementar `Serializable`, total, el código te queda:

```
package fips;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employe implements Serializable{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nom;
    private String empresa;
    private boolean jubilat;

    // Constructores.
    public Employe() {
        super();
    }

    public Employe(String nom, String empresa, boolean jubilat) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.jubilat = jubilat;
    }

    // Getters y Setters.
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public boolean isJubilat() {
        return jubilat;
    }

    public void setJubilat(boolean jubilat) {
        this.jubilat = jubilat;
    }

    // Re escritura de método heredado de Object.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employe [nom = " + nom + " | empresa = " + empresa + " | jubilat = " + jubilat + "]";
    }   

}
```

Ahora, lo que necesitas es escribir un fichero binario y luego leerlo, que es lo más normal, por tanto, una forma de hacerlo, sin complicarse mucho es:

```
package fips;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Crear Employes, en tu caso, desde el fichero txt.
        Employe a = new Employe("A", "HP", true);
        Employe b = new Employe("B", "ORACLE", false);
        Employe c = new Employe("C", "AMAZON", true);
        Employe d = new Employe("D", "SANTANDER", false);
        Employe e = new Employe("E", "FIPS", true);

        // Lo juntas en un objeto ya serializado, es decir, un ArrayList.
        ArrayList<Employe> employes = new ArrayList<>();
        employes.add(a);
        employes.add(b);
        employes.add(c);
        employes.add(d);
        employes.add(e);

        // Lo guardas en un fichero bonario, por ejemplo: employes.bin
        String ruta = "C:/TuUsuario/Escritorio/employes.bin";
        // Usamos try con recursos para olvidarnos de los cierres.
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(ruta))){
            // Escribo el único objeto, que es el ArrayList.
            oos.writeObject(employes);
        }catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Leer fichero employes.bin
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(ruta))){
            // En nuestro caso, ya sabemos que lo que leeremos es un ArrayList.
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Employe> objRead = (ArrayList<Employe>) ois.readObject();
            // Vemos sus datos.
            for (Employe employe : objRead) {
                System.out.println(employe.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Y por tanto, tienes ya la información accesible. Ten en cuenta que al usar esta forma, lo más óptimo es solo escribir un objeto por fichero, ya que al guardar cada objeto, se genera un cabecera... Eso ya te lo explicarán, pero centrate en que tiene que guardar un objeto, y dicho objeto puede contener los objetos que tu desees, y estos deben ser serializados.

En fin, para no enrollarme, tendrás en la salida de la cosola:

```
Employe [nom = A | empresa = HP | jubilat = true]
Employe [nom = B | empresa = ORACLE | jubilat = false]
Employe [nom = C | empresa = AMAZON | jubilat = true]
Employe [nom = D | empresa = SANTANDER | jubilat = false]
Employe [nom = E | empresa = FIPS | jubilat = true]
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: el problema que es por lo que me cuesta tanto es por que los datos los tengo que coger de un archivo TXT. Por eso la complicación.. T_T

Comment: Es decir tu los creas directamente.. el problema es que yo tengo que leerlos.. y luego guardarlos en binario. No puedo tocar el programa base. Ni puedo hacerlo manualmente.. ya que el fichero tiene 5 empleados pero si tuviera 10.000 mil...

Comment: Vale, pues yo me he limitado a responderte a: ¿Cómo guardar objetos en un fichero binario? Pero si necesitas que te ayuden en la lectura, debes poner el formato que tiene el fichero de texto.

Answer (score 1):

La manera más fácil si ya implementaste la interfaz `Serializable` de guardar un objeto como binario es usar un `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
Serializable employee = new Employee();
// colocar datos al employee
File archivo = new File("ruta/a/archivo")
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream(archivo));
oos.writeObject(employee);
oos.close();
```

Eso te escribe un archivo con tu objeto completo incluyendo sus datos.
Solamente asegurate que todos los campos incluidos también sean `Serializable`.

Se recomienda de atrapar un par de posibles excepciones con `try...catch`.